# Showing that the normalizer of $O(n,\mathbb{C})$ in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is given as $\mathbb{C}^* \cdot O(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, orthogonal-matrices

I want to prove that the normalizer of $O(n,\mathbb{C})$ in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is  $\mathbb{C}^* \cdot O(n,\mathbb{C})$. For now i had the following idea:

---

Assume, that $A \in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is in the normalizer, i.e. satisfyies
$$A \cdot O(n,\mathbb{C}) \cdot A^{-1} \subseteq O(n,\mathbb{C}).$$
We have to show, that $A=\lambda U$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$ and $U \in O(n,\mathbb{C})$. According to the hint, $O(n,\mathbb{C})$ preserves a unique, up to scaling, nonzero quadratic form with corresponding matrix $I$. If $A$ is now a change of basis matrix, it preserves the form of $O(n,\mathbb{C})$ up to scaling. We get
$$A^t I A = A^t A = \mu I$$
for some $\mu \in \mathbb{C}^*$. Set $\mu := \lambda^2$, then there exists $U \in O(n,\mathbb{C})$ s.th.
$$A^tA = \mu I = \mu U^tU = (\lambda U)^t(\lambda U)$$
and we conclude $A=\lambda U$.

Comment: Do you already know that $O(n,C)$ preserves unique, up to scaling, nonzero quadratic form? This property is the key to the proof.

Comment: Well, i do know that $O(n,\mathbb{C})=\{X \in GL(n,\mathbb{C}) \mid X^t X =I\}$ so the matrix corresponding to the form is the identity matrix, i.e. $X^t I X = I$. But how does this help me?

Comment: The key, as I said, is **uniqueness** of the invariant form.

Comment: I still don´t quite understand your hint. In the first place, isn´t over $\mathbb{C}$ every non-degenerate quadratic form $F$ eqivalent to $I$, i.e. $\exists U \in GL(n,\mathbb{C}): UFU^{-1}=I$? Then the corresponding orthogonal groups are conjugated and hence up to isomorphism can be identified with $O(n,\mathbb{C})$...

Comment: If $A$ is a change of basis matrix, what form is preserved by $A\cdot O(n,C)\cdot A^{-1}$?

Comment: Well, if $A$ is in the normalizer, then the form it preserves is the form on $O(n,\mathbb{C})$, i.e. $I$. But i can´t conclude from that, that $A= \lambda U$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$ and $U \in O(n,\mathbb{C})$, can I?

Comment: Hopefully this works now, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ is nonsingular and for every complex orthogonal matrix $Q$, there exists a complex orthogonal matrix $Q'$ such that $AQA^{-1}=Q'$. Then $AQ=Q'A$ and in turn, $Q^TA^TAQ=A^T(Q'^TQ')A=A^TA$. You may continue from here. The hint in your question refers to the fact that if $Q^TA^TAQ=A^TA$ for every complex orthogonal $Q$, $A^TA$ must be a scalar multiple of $I$.